# preg_replace remove multiple differing parts of string between patterns

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

**This is a very small portion of a string i have scraped:**

SEPVALAjazz(music)SEPVALC5.59SEPVALAlatin(music)SEPVALAcountry(music)SEPVALC6.70SEPVALArock(music)SEPVALC5.89SEPVALAdance(music)SEPVALAworld(music)SEPVALC6.70

I have manipulated the string with regex to insert the "SEPVALA" and "SEPVALC" values.  I wish to remove the string between the patterns **"SEPVALA"** and **"(music)SEPVALA"** where ever it occurs in the text. In the above example this would remove "latin" and "dance".

**The desired result would be:**

SEPVALAjazz(music)SEPVALC5.59SEPVALAcountry(music)SEPVALC6.70SEPVALArock(music)SEPVALC5.89SEPVALAworld(music)SEPVALC6.70

**The code i am implementing at the moment is:**

$pattern="/SEPVALA(.+?)\(music\)SEPVALA/";

$replacement="SEPVALA";

$newstring=preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, *$originalstring*);

However this removes too much of the string as the regex engine picks up the very first **"SEPVALA"** and removes everything forward from this point until **"(music)SEPVALA"** (as it should do!) I need a method to scan backwards from **"(music)SEPVALA"** removing the offending text and stopping at the next **"SEPVALA"** before then moving forwards to the next match of **"(music)SEPVALA"** and so on.  Or any other method to accomplish this.  Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing the following pattern with an empty string:

```
SEPVALA((?!SEPVAL[AC]).)+(?<=\(music\))(?=SEPVALA)
```

Example: http://www.rubular.com/r/ZCfJQ4ey2O

Explanation: This works by matching `SEPVALA`, then matching one character at a time until either `SEPVALA` or `SEPVALC` can match, by using a negative lookahead with repetition.  At this point we have matched from `SEPVALA` to just before either `SEPVALA` or `SEPVALC`, so we just need to make sure the previously matched characters are `(music)`, and the next characters are `SEPVALA`.

Full code:

```
$pattern="/SEPVALA((?!SEPVAL[AC]).)+(?<=\\(music\\))(?=SEPVALA)/";
$replacement="";
$newstring=preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $originalstring);
```

Comment: This is exactly what i needed.  Thank you, i am humbled by your great knowledge!